# Combining work items from projects in Azure Organization

Tags: azure, azure-devops, workitem, user-stories

We have different organizations and each developer has work items spanning across these organizations.

I want a single report containing work items from all these organizations assigned to a developer.

So the option I was going with was to create a new project and use [Organization scoped queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/account-scoped-queries?view=azure-devops#organization-scoped-queries) to create work items in the newly created project for each developer. But then we need a new service which will also monitor and set the state of the newly created work items to be same as the state in the original project/organization.

Just wanted to check if there is an existing solution in Azure Dev Ops that does this. If not, is this the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm curious what requirement led you to this approach? Why do you want to sync work item states across organizations? Why the duplication? Normally I see organizations having unique work items in different organizations and using work item links to point to their parent/children in other organizations.

Comment: How is your problem progressing? Is the following answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> we need a new service which will also monitor and set the state of the
>   newly created work items to be same as the state in the original
>   project/organization.

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently impossible in azure devops. There is no such way in azure devops to synchronize the state of work items in different organizations.

In addition, as Wouter is curious in the comment, why do you want to synchronize the work item state of different organizations? Work items in different organizations should be independent of each other.

The process of creating projects under different organizations may also be different, which may be agile, scrum... or a custom process,this leads to differences in work item types in different projects. If you integrate the work items of these different processes into one project, it could cause confusion.